# How to call the dynamically created panel on next/prev click of paging?

Tags: extjs

I have a layout like this:

```
Ext.define('App.view.Demo', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    requires:[
            'Ext.toolbar.Paging'
    ],
    xtype: 'app-main-demo',

    autoScroll: true,

    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        pack: 'start',
        align: 'stretch'
    },

    frame: true,

    initComponent: function() {
        Id = this.Id;
        var store = Ext.create('APP.store.Demo');
        store.proxy.url = store.proxy.url + this.Id;
        Ext.apply(this, {
            store: store
        });

        this.items = [],
        this.bbar = Ext.create('Ext.PagingToolbar', {
            store: store,
            displayInfo: true,
            displayMsg: 'Displaying topics {0} - {1} of {2}',
            emptyMsg: "No topics to display",
            listeners: {
                beforechange: function(){
                    //do some stuff
                }

            }
        }),

        this.callParent();
    },
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function(obj,eOpts){
             obj.store.currentPage = 1;
             obj.store.load(function(records, operation, success) {
                console.log(records.length);
                if (records.length > 0){
                        var panel = Ext.create('App.view.Demo2',{
                        Id: Id,
                        oId: records[(obj.store.currentPage - 1)].data.id,
                        rId: records[(obj.store.currentPage - 1)].data.request_id
                     }) 
                    obj.add(panel);
                    obj.doLayout();
              }
            })
        }
    }
});
```

Here I am dynamically creating the panel(Demo2). On next or prev click in pagination of Demo, it should draw the structure dynamically(passing respective oId and rId to Demo2).

Demo2 consists of extends from Ext.panel.Panel, On the basis of the oId and rId passed I am quering the db and changing the color of the button.

Code For Demo2:

```
Ext.define('Ext.view.Demo2', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',

    xtype: 'app-main-demo2',
    layout: {
        type: 'fit',
        pack: 'start',
        align: 'stretch'
    },

    initComponent: function() {
        var store = Ext.create('Ext.store.Demo2');
        store.proxy.url = store.proxy.url + this.oId + '/' + this.rId;
        Ext.apply(this, {
            store: store
        });
        this.items= []

        this.callParent();
    },
listeners: {
        afterrender: function(obj, eOpts){
            var status;
            obj.store.load(function(records, operation, success) {
                 status= records[0].data.status;
                 if (status == 'Complete') {
                        var Panel = Ext.create('Ext.view.Demo3',{
                             style: {
                            background: '#A9A9A9'
                        }
                            flex:2,
            text: 'Completed'
                    }) ;
                    obj.add(Panel);
                    obj.doLayout();
                    }

});
```

Here, I am dynamically created Demo3 that extens  Ext.button.Button.

Code For Demo3:

```
Ext.define('Ext.view.Demo3', {
    extend: 'Ext.button.Button',
    requires:[

    ],

    xtype: 'app-main-demo3',
    layout: {
        type: 'fit',
        pack: 'start',
        align: 'stretch'
    }
});
```

In Demo, On prev and next click how to destroy the previous structure and load the new structure. Thanks in Advance